# Studying series convergence with small o

Tags: calculus

I got the following term from the general term of my series:
$$\left(\sqrt{n}+1\right)^n$$
I worked it out by using small-o approach. Then it became:
$$(\sqrt{n})^n\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^n=n^{n/2}(1+o(1))^n$$

Now, I was wondering whether the quantity $(1+o(1))^n$ can be considered as $(1+o(1))$. I would say that it is not possible because that quantity is an indeterminate form as $n\rightarrow +\infty$.

What do you guys think about it?

Answer (score 1):

No.  $$(\sqrt{n})^n\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^n=(\sqrt{n})^n\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{\sqrt{n}*\sqrt{n}}$$
Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{\sqrt{n}}=e$
The result should be $n^{n/2}e^\sqrt{n}$

Answer (score 0):

Since $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}(\sqrt n +1)^n=\infty$, it follows that the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\sqrt n +1)^n$$
has to diverges.